# How to use SimpleMemberShip Provider in Asp.net MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Although i have been through this article 
http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/

but i dont know is it correct way to use simple membership provider in asp.net mvc4 application.

Moreover, i want to know what is difference between DefaultMembership provider and
SimpleMembership Providers

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please take a look into the following article:

[SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates).

In particular, its on supposedly respectable ASP.NET web portal and the title you looking for is "SimpleMembership: The future of membership for ASP.NET".

The article has all the links you need to get started and have all the answers to your question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Comment: evidently they moved the article. found it and fixed the link, thanks for letting me know.